# How do i display conditional warning dialog in apexpage on buttonclick?

Tags: visualforce

I have a page with delete button. I would like to show a custom warning dialog when delete button is clicked. I cannot use onClick confirmDelete() js method as I need to customize the warning message based on some business logic.

In the controller I thought of writing an action for delete, but not sure how to show javascript warning dialog from there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show a JS dialog from within your controller, the best you can do is show a dialog on click of the button (you can use `jQueryUI` for customization). When clicked on true, you can call an `actionFunction` to delete the record, if clicked on false, just dismiss the dialog.

This will save any additional ajax calls to the controller

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to display confirmation window before any action performed on button click.

```
<apex:commandButton id="delete" value="Delete" action="{!DeleteData}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return};"/>
```

i thing this might be usefull for you if im wrong then plz correct me.

Comment: Basically I would like to do validation and based on the validation result show a warning dialog, and if user clicks OK button I need to execute delete action.

Comment: On what condition of validation do you like to show warning dialog?
Suppose validation is false then what? and if true then what?

Comment: Basically I would like to do validation and based on the validation result show a warning dialog, and if user clicks OK button I need to execute delete action. Some thing like  <br/>   public void deleteRecord()  { 

    // Validate 
       Boolean validateResult = validateDelete(this.id);

    // show warning dialog based on validateResult  
       executeDelete(this.id);         
 }<br/> I would like to know if there is way to save intermediate result, show warning dialog based on the result and then call another function in controller